# read-only ldap client setup

Tags: openvpn, remote, ldap, openldap, cloud

I have a Debian Linux box hosted on the cloud that I want to provide mail services with (Postfix/Dovecot). I want it to access my openLDAP server at home for authentication and to provide users email access.

How can I setup the LDAP client/server communication securely? The cloud server should have read-only access to LDAP as well. The home server runs OS X 10.10 Server.

I'm guessing a VPN connection to my home would be required unless LDAP has SSL support and would provide enough security using encryption. I have OpenVPN server setup at home that I can connect to.